# Drawing Context and Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, racket

I've been trying to make a user application for drawing tileset bitmaps, so something a bit like this (multiple layers of fg color/alpha, bg color/alpha, and characters):

[image]

Creating the bitmap isn't a problem, but now I'm at the part where I'd like to edit and make modifications to it. I'm satisifed with the bitmap output but I notice if I've already printed a bitmap once I can no longer make changes to it

[image]

I've already checked the documentation for [bitmap%](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html), [bitmap-dc%](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap-dc_.html), and [dc%](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html) but I couldn't find any information if this is intentional. Am I missing a step inbetween?

**Update**: I notice that if I copy the bitmap to another bitmap after drawing than the changes will visible in the new bitmap but the old one doesn't

[image]

Here is the sample code

```
#lang racket

(require racket/draw)

(define bmp1 (make-bitmap 128 128))
(define bdc1 (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap bmp1]))
(send bdc1 set-pen "yellow" 1 'solid)
(send bdc1 set-brush "black" 'solid)
(send bdc1 draw-rectangle 0 0 128 128)
(send bdc1 draw-rectangle 0 0 64 64)
(send bdc1 draw-line 0 0 128 128)
bmp1
(send bdc1 set-pen "red" 4 'solid)
(send bdc1 draw-line 128 0 0 128)
bmp1

(define bmp2 (make-bitmap 128 128))
(define bdc2 (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap bmp2]))
(define d (send bdc2 draw-bitmap bmp1 0 0))
bmp2
bmp1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 90% sure that you are seeing the results of a bug in DrRacket.
And I am almost sure that the bug has been fixed already.

```
https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/
```

Can I talk you into installing the development version from the above link?

The bug in question:
          https://github.com/racket/drracket/commit/2d3205571cb4d1d38335c4bac84810e72777c769

Comment: Just to include the conversation from IRC should others come by, I had tested on Windows/Linux using 6.5 and 6.3 (what I had coincidentally intalled before upgrading to 6.5) but I'm having the same results. http://i.imgur.com/QqgVPtg.jpg http://i.imgur.com/9r252yC.jpg

Comment: Hi. The bug is still in 6.5.  You need the development version. Get it from the link to snapshots above.